Extract text from pdf in correct visual order from PDF
while using a Python library to extract text from a PDF, the order of the selected text doesn't match what you visually see on the screen? For instance, when i copy some text at top of page, then a table, and finally some more text, but when you paste, everything appears in a different order. Even when examining the layout dictionary, the extracted text retains this unexpected order. Why does this discrepancy occur, and what steps can be taken to resolve it?
I tried using sort, and even tried arranging the text in natural reading order, but I ran into trouble when applying this method to a PDF with a two-column layout. Specifically, I want to extract text column by column if the PDF follows a column layout. By the way, I'm dealing with extracting text from various complex layouts. However, when I use sorting, I encounter problems with layouts that have multiple columns. I'm looking for a solution that addresses text wrapping, encoding, or any other issues causing the problem.

There's no "issue" and no "problem" here.  PDF files were never designed to be a data exchange format.  They were designed to be a virtual printer, and nothing more.  Every character in a PDF file has X and Y coordinates, but they aren't stored in order, and words don't even have to be stored together.  Some PDF packages can give you the X and Y of each text blob; perhaps you could use that to reconstruct the visual order.

To underpin what already has been said: If a page has text with a total of N characters, then there are N! different ways (well, a bit less maybe because some chars may be the same) to create this page with identical visual appearance ... and only one of these alternatives will extract the text in "natural" reading sequence when using naive text extraction. PyMuPDF offers ways to extract text together with each character's coordinates. Note: I am a maintainer and the original creator of PyMuPDF.

Try Adobe's PDF Extract API. It's a REST API but has Python SDK. It can detect columns and reading order. https://acrobatservices.adobe.com/dc-visualizer-app/index.html

The layout in a PDF is in effect letter by letter sometimes (luckily often) those letters can be a whole line in a block (not always as word groups).
So if we print this page this Question first line print may be:
"while using a Python library to extract text from a PDF, the order of the selected text doesn't match"
OR
"while)-50(using)-50(a)-50(Python)-50(l)1(i)1(b)1(r)1(a)1(r)1
(y)" etc.
Thus Abracadabra can be written as seen here.

However inside the PDF what you extract may be composed like this.
BT
40 TL /1 18 Tf 1 0 0 1 15 800 Tm T*
(PlainText = http://foersom.com/net/HowTo/data/OoPdfFormExample.pdf) Tj
/1 16 Tf T* (12  letters.) Tj 20 TL T* (9) Tj 1 0 0 1 42 720 Tm T* (letters.) Tj
1 0 0 1 15 700 Tm T* (A) Tj 1 0 0 1 40 700 Tm T* (a) Tj 1 0 0 1 57 700 Tm T* (a) Tj 1 0 0 1 75 700 Tm T* (a) Tj 1 0 0 1 98 700 Tm T* (a) Tj
1 0 0 1 26 700 Tm T* (b) Tj 1 0 0 1 84 700 Tm T* (b) Tj 
1 0 0 1 49 700 Tm T* (c) Tj
1 0 0 1 66 700 Tm T* (d) Tj
1 0 0 1 92.5 700 Tm T* (r) Tj 1 0 0 1 34.5 700 Tm T* (r) Tj 40 TL T*
(goto page in another PDF) Tj 20 TL T*
(Also plain text = https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf#page=2) Tj
25 TL /1 11 Tf 1 0 0 1 154.5 760 Tm T*
(Sign and Secure this file.txt as a PDF with Adobe Reader) Tj
1 0 0 1 149.5 695 Tm T*
(or click https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/online/sign-pdf.html) Tj
ET

So a Laser Beam in an Appple Printer has no problems burning onto the drum in this order,
A a a a a
b b
c
d
r r

Adobe Accessibility Reader does fairly well, in sorting some inputs but why middle first and where did 9 go ? also why Abracadabra S?

What we would like is something like the PDF page Layout as per this -fixed lay-out-put from Poppler PDFtoTeXT using a Right click on file via try.cmd.
for /L %%f in (2,1,9) do pdftotext -layout -nopgbrk -enc UTF-8 -fixed %%f "%~1"  "%~dpn1-%%f.txt"
PlainText = http://foersom.com/net/HowTo/data/OoPdfFormExample.pdf
                  Sign and Secure this file.txt as a PDF with Adobe Reader
12 letters.
9 letters.
Abracadabra
                 or click https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/online/sign-pdf.html

  goto page in another PDF
  Also plain text = https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf#page=2

